# Attributes of an object are been lose with using axios in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using axios, I don't understand why some attributes of objects get lost. Please, look at this piece of code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-message-box :data="mBox" />
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" sort-by="calories" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat color="white">
          <v-toolbar-title>Coplaint list</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-divider class="mx-4" inset vertical></v-divider>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="btnNewItem" dark class="mb-2">New Item</v-btn>
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>

              <v-card-text>
                <v-complaint :complaint="editedItem" />
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-toolbar>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
        <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:no-data>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vComplaint from "../create/v-complaint";
import Api from "@/api/Api";
import vMessageBox from "../commons/v-message-box";
import MessageBox from "../commons/messagebox.js";
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "v-complaint-table",
  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    headers: [],
    items: [],
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {},
    defaultItem: null,
    mBox: new MessageBox(),
  }),
  props: ["patient"],

  methods: {

    // Some functions ....
    editItem(item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.items.indexOf(item);
      this.editedItem = this.toObject(item);
      this.dialog = true;
    },

    deleteItem(item) {
      const index = this.items.indexOf(item);
      confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?") &&
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
    },

    close() {
      this.dialog = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      });
    },

    save() {
      let mBox = this.mBox
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        let complaint = this.editedItem;
        Api()
          .put("/complaint_request", {
            complaint
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Updated");
          })
          .catch(e => {
            mBox.showMessage("Error", e, "error");
            console.log(e);
          });
        Object.assign(
          this.items[this.editedIndex],
          this.toTemplate(this.editedItem)
        );
      } else {
        var complaint = this.editedItem;
        var _this = this
        console.log(this.editedItem)
        Api()
          .post("/complaint_request", {
            complaint
          })
          .then(respone => {
            _this.editedItem.id = respone.data;
            console.log(_this.editedItem)
            _this.items.push(this.toTemplate(_this.editedItem));
          })
          .catch(e => {
            mBox.showMessage("Error", e, "error");
            console.log(e);
          });
      }
      this.close();
    },
};
</script>
```

In the first print, I take that attributes of `this.editedItem`

[image: the result of the first print]

In the second print, I take that attributes of `this.editedItem`

[image: the result of the second print]

I can't understand why the character and date attributes are lost in the second print. I know that both attributes are nested. I think the problem is connected with axios and its Asynchronous.

Api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api',
        //baseURL: 'http://192.168.137.1:8080/api',
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'common': '',
            //'token': ''
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance... Could be a scoping issue with `this`. Would need to see some more code to know for sure, but you could try , before you'r API call, to set a variable to maintain your scope, such as `var _this = this;` Then, inside of your .then() response, use _this instead. Just a shot in the dark based on what I see.

Comment: You are setting the response as id of the user . I don't know if that is want you want to do `this.editedItem.id = respone.data`

Comment: Change `console.log(this.editedItem)` to `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.editedItem))` and I bet you'll see some changes. The console is **not a debugging tool**. I suggest you use your browser's JavaScript debugger instead

Comment: I am sorry for the understandable question, this is vue js. And I am trying to send a new instance to the server for creating, and the server sends back the id of the created instance(I am new on web programming, so I don't see another option to do this ). I put the id of the created instance to work on the client-side (editing, or deleting). I have added some pieces of code to the question. I sorry, `var _this = this` didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `close()`, you assign

```
this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
```

Since you call `this.close` *before* the promise in `save` resolves, then `this.editedItem` gets reset to `this.defaultItem`, which I assume is missing the date.

So it's best to put the call to `close` in the promise `.then` callback.

Edit: fix names

Comment: But I don't understand why the `close` method works before finishing `if .. else` statement? Asynchronous?

Comment: Actually, the `.then` callback happens *after* the `if...else` statement. @Musulmon. (The close method still happens after the if/else.)